# composer require spatie/laravel-backup

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I keep getting errors when I type `composer require spatie/laravel-backup`

```
Nessrines-MacBook-Pro-2:tfw nessrine$ composer require spatie/laravel-backup

Using version ^4.16 for spatie/laravel-backup
./composer.json has been updated

> php artisan clear-compiled

The compiled services file has been removed.

Loading composer repositories with package information

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Problem 1
    - Installation request for spatie/laravel-backup ^4.16 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-backup[4.16.0].
    - Conclusion: remove spatie/db-dumper 1.5.1
    - Conclusion: don't install spatie/db-dumper 1.5.1
    - spatie/laravel-backup 4.16.0 requires spatie/db-dumper ^2.6 -> satisfiable by spatie/db-dumper[2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.7.0].
    - Can only install one of: spatie/db-dumper[2.6.0, 1.5.1].
    - Can only install one of: spatie/db-dumper[2.6.1, 1.5.1].
    - Can only install one of: spatie/db-dumper[2.7.0, 1.5.1].
    - Installation request for spatie/db-dumper (locked at 1.5.1) -> satisfiable by spatie/db-dumper[1.5.1].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
Nessrines-MacBook-Pro-2:tfw nessrine$ composer require spatie/laravel-backup’
[image]

Comment: have you fulfilled all the requirements mentioned here.. ?https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-backup/v4/requirements

Comment: how to check  .?

Comment: You might have another package that requires db-dumper version 1.5.x which conflicts with this one. You should check the composer.json for each required package you have to make sure they're compatible with laravel-backup.

Comment: ok i will try to find the required version

Comment: @apokryfos op shared the composer.json file. The package which op's trying to installed is already installed with an older version. All that's needed is to the updated the package or remove the older one and do a clean install of the newest version.

Comment: Do you have a `composer.lock` file is so, could you share it?

Comment: https://kopy.io/BuU8Y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the outdated package `spatie/db-dumper` manually before installing `spatie/laravel-backup` which requires a newer version of the db dumper package.

You can remove `spatie/db-dumper` package from your `composer.json` file and then install. Or run `composer remove spatie/db-dumper` and then proceed to install the backup package.

**Edit**

From your comment it's clear that you already have an older version of the package `spatie/laravel-backup` installed.

**Edit 2**

Since you're obviously having trouble updating this package, here's the most simplest way that i can explain this.

Run `composer remove spatie/laravel-backup`

Go to `config/app.php` and remove the line `Spatie\Backup\BackupServiceProvider::class`

Run `composer require spatie/laravel-backup`

Follow further instructions for the package, which also includes adding the service provider back in app.php

https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-backup/v4/installation-and-setup

Comment: i don't have spatie/db-dumper in the first place

Comment: @NisrineHafi share your composer.json file contents.

Comment: @NisrineHafi updated my answer. You already have an older version of the `spatie/laravel-backup` installed. Remove it first and then install the newer version.

Comment: Or `composer require spatie/laravel-backup --update-with-dependencies` might also work

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Class 'Spatie\Backup\BackupServiceProvider' not found

Comment: @NisrineHafi when you uninstall the package and reinstall it, the service provider which was added for the old package in app.php config file would throw a missing error. Anyway i updated the answer to make things simpler for you. Just update the version number in your composer and run the update command.

Comment: i did run it but the same thing

Comment: @NisrineHafi i updated my answer to be as simple as possible. Basically you already have this package installed, but an older version. So you need to remove it and install the newer version of the package as you're failing to update it.

Comment: but now i have this error when ii press"php artisan backup:run"                                   [Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException]                  
  Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Notifications\Dispatcher] is not instantiable.

Comment: @NisrineHafi that is the issue with the package, a right place to ask that would be the issues section on github. All i can recommend is checking the compatibility and requirements of the package from your end.